# How to simplify numeric class name in CSS?

Tags: css

Is it possible to simplify this to make it work infinitely when the number increase ?

```css
.a1 .t1 {color: rgb(40, 40, 255);}
.a2 .t2 {color: rgb(40, 40, 255);}
.a3 .t3 {color: rgb(40, 40, 255);}
.a4 .t4 {color: rgb(40, 40, 255);}
.a5 .t5 {color: rgb(40, 40, 255);}
.a6 .t6 {color: rgb(40, 40, 255);}
```

Is it possible with attributes that change relative to the number ? Or is it possible to do it with a CSS variable ?

```css
.a1 .line {transform: translateX(calc((830px / 6 + 1px) * 0));}
.a2 .line {transform: translateX(calc((830px / 6 + 1px) * 1));}
.a3 .line {transform: translateX(calc((830px / 6 + 1px) * 2));}
.a4 .line {transform: translateX(calc((830px / 6 + 1px) * 3));}
.a5 .line {transform: translateX(calc((830px / 6 + 1px) * 4));}
.a6 .line {transform: translateX(calc((830px / 6 + 1px) * 5));}
```

Comment: Unfortunately no. I wish it could be possible with [attr()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr()), maybe someday...

Comment: It can only be achieved by JavaScript I guess or you can use Sass/Less to simplify things.

Answer (score 1):

If you can change the HTML at all, you can use a CSS variable:

```css
.a .line { 
    transform: translateX(calc((830px / 6 + 1px) * var(--offset, 0))); 
}
```

```HTML
<div class="a" style="--offset:0;">
    <div class="line">...</div>
</div>
<div class="a" style="--offset:1;">
    <div class="line">...</div>
</div>
<div class="a" style="--offset:2;">
    <div class="line">...</div>
</div>
```

[Using CSS custom properties (variables)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties)

If your HTML is fixed, then unfortunately you're going to need to use Javascript as mentioned in the comments. For example:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('*').forEach(el => {
    el.classList.forEach(c => {
        const match = c.match(/^a(\d+)$/);
        if (match) {
            el.classList.add("a");
            el.style.setProperty("--offset", match[1]);
        }
    });
});
```